# retrieve informations from a website for my database

Tags: php

There is this website http://www.cinecity.nc/default.asp that displays movies at the theater with hours of projections, titles of the movies..etc.

Is it possible to retrieve some infos and add them in my database ?

I'm quite a novice in php.

I've tried this in my cinema.php file :

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.cinecity.nc/default.asp");
echo $content;
```

And it displays me lots of informations. How can I, now, retrieve "movieTitle", "hours" and things like this ?

Thx

Comment: Look into DOMDocument http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: The contents of the website are going to change, so even though you try to write a code to extract the movie title etc. In the near future if its change, then you will be keep changing the code.

Comment: Exact ! Didn't think of that. But maybe I can, then, create a php file that is automatically triggered each week ? Possible ?

Comment: @user5870211 I think you need get an api where you can get the details, there are many api providers for that. so that you dont have to steal any data from other websites.

Comment: Even if the data are "public" I need an API ? Can't I use `file_get_contents` and then search in the result all the "movies" and store them in a variable ?